# Edit html file in batch file

Tags: batch-file, replace, cmd

I have a script in which I read html files which I want to edit. Here I paste the code which calls :remove_redundant_columns subroutine.

It should remove the spaces/white spaces from begin of each line and remove  from html file. Only problem is that it adds extra text like = to lines which are almost empty, just have few tabs.

The html file which I downloaded is from hidemyass.com/proxy-list/1

```
call parse_proxy.bat remove_redundant_columns !FILENAME!
exit /b

:remove_redundant_columns
REM Remove whitespaces from begin of lines and <span></span>
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%t in (%1) do (
   SET S=%%t
   SET S=!S:^<span^>^</span^>=!
   if NOT "!S!"=="" >>$tmp$ echo !S!
   )
del %1
REN $tmp$ %1
exit /b
```

Comment: That's not something you should even attempt in a batch file. Seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you believe, that's your only problem... You need to check, if your variable S contains content.

That's required, as substitution on an undefined variable will not produce an undefined/empty variable, the new content will be the substitution text.

```
:remove_redundant_columns
REM Remove whitespaces from begin of lines and <span></span>
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%t in (%1) do (
   SET S=%%t
   if defined S (
     SET S=!S:^<span^>^</span^>=!
     >>$tmp$ echo !S!
   )
)
```

As dbenham stated, you got many other problems,
and one additional problem is the `echo !S!` command itself.

`ECHO` has some nasty side effects on different content.
If the content is empty (or only spaces) then it will print it's currently state
`ECHO IS OFF`
If the content is `OFF` or `ON` it will NOT be echoed, it will only change the state.
And if the content is `/?` it will echo the help instead of `/?`.

To solve this you could simply change `ECHO !S!` to `ECHO(!S!` and all problems are gone.

Comment: @JohnBoe - Need to verify S is still defined after performing search and replace: `if defined S >>$tmp$ echo !S!`

Comment: I know what you mean, but it isn't enough, as a singl. space would also fail

Answer (score 1):

jeb already solved your = problem (once the extra IF DEFINED check is added to his answer). But you may have at least one other problem.

I agree with Joey that you should not be using batch to manipulate HTML like this. But, if you really want to...

Your potential problem is that HTML usually has `!` characters sprinkled within. Your code uses delayed expansion, but that causes corruption of FOR variable expansion when it contains `!` character(s). The solution is to toggle delayed expansion on and off within your loop.

```
:remove_redundant_columns
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
REM Remove whitespaces from begin of lines and <span></span>
(
  FOR /f "usebackq eol= tokens=*" %%t in ("%~1") do (
    SET S=%%t
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    if defined S SET "S=!S:<span></span>=!"
    for /f "eol= tokens=*" %%S in ("!S!") do if "%%S" neq "" echo %%S
    endlocal
  )
) >>$tmp$
move /y $tmp$ "%~1"
exit /b
```

Other minor changes that were made to the code:

- The search and replace can be simplified by using quotes so that special chars don't need to be escaped.
- You can replace DEL and REN with a single MOVE.
- Redirection is more efficient (faster) if you redirect once using an outer set of parentheses
- You may need to search a file name that has spaces and or special characters, in which case you will need to quote the name. But that requires the FOR /F "USEBACKQ" option.

***EDIT***

Modified code to strip leading spaces after `<span></span>` has been replaced to eliminate potential of a line containing nothing but spaces and/or tabs.

Also set EOL to space to prevent stripping of lines beginning with ;

Comment: The `if defined S (echo !S!)` only solve one problem for empty strings, but it still fails with a spaces, or `ON`, `OFF`, `/?`. You know that `(echo(!S!)` solves all problems here :-)

Comment: Oooh - I never considered that there might be nothing but spaces after `<span></span>` is removed. Yes, using `ECHO(` would help, but I'm guessing the OP wouldn't want a line containing only spaces to be printed. Postponing the FOR /F stripping of leading spaces and tabs until after the search/replace should help.